# Replacing string in script from another script

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a Python script with a string, I want to replace the string using another script. I am not allowed to modify anything else in the original script other than the string in question.

script.py

```
string1 = 'OriginalValue'
```

replaceString.py

```
string1 = 'newValue'
```

script.py

```
string1 = 'newValue'
```

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Comment: *"and if so, how?"* - edit the `script.py` file like any other text file.

Comment: You can `open` the file (`script.py`) like a text file, read the lines until you find `OriginalValue` and change it to `newValue`.

Comment: So you want to change the sourcecode of script.py. Since there's no easy way for replaceString.py to know where to find your line string1 = etc., tag that line with a  likely unique comment, e.g. # __x__change__x__, then read it as a text file, find the line using a regular expression or <substring> in <string>, change it to your liking and save your file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following replaceString.py should do it:

```
with open('script.py') as myFile:
    content = myFile.readlines()

with open('script.py', 'w') as myFile:
    for line in content:
        newLine = line.replace("string1 = 'OriginalValue'", "string1 = 'newValue'")
        myFile.write(newLine)
```

Comment: It's much neater to: 1. use e.g. `"string1 = 'OriginalValue'"` (note quotes); and 2. check the line before the `replace` (e.g. `if line.startswith.('string1 = ')`).